# Problema de cálculo

Tags: php, javascript

Estou realizando alguns cálculos no Front-End para não necessitar fazer requisição para o Back-End.

Porém me deparei com o seguinte problema nos cálculos.

No JS:

```
490 * 60 / 60 = 490
490 / 60 * 60 = 489.99999999999994
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gt6nwwjr/)

No PHP:

```
 490 * 60 / 60 = 490
 490 / 60 * 60 = 490
```

[PHPSandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c9cdf1241a0760872fc5e2f771388ee764b36b2)

- Porque isso acontece no JS e no PHP não?

Comment: PHP só exibe 490, mas na real é o mesmo valor que o JS. Basta usar o `number_format` para aumentar as casas decimais: `number_format(490/60*60, 14)`. E isso ocorre devido a representação dos números com ponto flutuante, já discutido aqui no site.

Comment: Vou ler sobre isso e tentar entender melhor, porque isso é "novidade" para mim.

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)